# Which Class In The JDK Creates The JRMI ProtocolAck?

Tags: java, rmi, wireshark

Some of my (Java 7) RMI calls have been taking longer than expected.

When I inspect the packet capture with Wireshark I am seeing the following:

```
client → server TCP [SYN, ECN, CWR] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
server → client TCP [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 WS=512
client → server TCP [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=2102272 Len=0
client → server RMI JRMI, Version: 2, StreamProtocol
server → client TCP [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=8 Win=29696 Len=0
server → client RMI JRMI, ProtocolAck
client → server RMI Continuation
server → client TCP [ACK] Seq=21 Ack=27 Win=29696 Len=0
client → server RMI JRMI, Call
```

FYI: "JRMI" is just the text that Wireshark uses for decoding the protocol.

The actual protocol definition is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/rmi/spec/rmi-protocol3.html

The delay is appearing at the `server → client  RMI JRMI, ProtocolAck` (~3.5s) *before* the actual RMI call is being made.

The majority of the ProtocolAck in the packet capture take microseconds to complete.

This makes me think that is isn't anything to do with my code per-se but something with the runtime or the infrastructure.

FYI: There was no major GC at this time and the minor GC took 97 ms but that is running in parallel and not stop the world.

I'm trying to determine what could cause this delay in the ProtocolAck.

Which classes in the JDK are responsible for the ProtocolAck?

Comment: I don;t know what JRMI, is but the protocol used by RMI in the JDK is called JRMP. Are you using JBoss? or something else with its own implementation of RMI?

Comment: Updated the question explaining that JRMI is the Wireshark text for decoding the standard JDK RMI protocol.

Answer (score 0):

The `sun.rmi.transport.TransportConstants` defines the protocol definition

https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/rmi/transport/TransportConstants.java

This is then used by `sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport`

https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/rmi/transport/tcp/TCPTransport.java

and `sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel`

https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/rmi/transport/tcp/TCPChannel.java

The ProtocolAck is sent in the TCPTransport class [here](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/rmi/transport/tcp/TCPTransport.java#L775)